# How to make ES6 modules and JSX working without server-side build?

Tags: jsx, es6-modules

I want to use JSX together with the ES6 modules, and want to do so without a server-side build.

My index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <script type="text/babel" data-type="module">
        import 'test' from './test.js'
        ...
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My test.js:

```js
export default function test(props) {
    return <div>
        ...
    </div>
}
```

Result: I get an error in the browser's console saying

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

So I am assuming that babel did not pre-process the loaded file. How can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

This was linked to a GitHub Issue for DataFormsJS jsxLoader which along with a custom LazyLoad component provides for similar functionality however it doesn't use the standard `import fn from './file.js'` syntax.

https://dataformsjs.com/en/

https://github.com/dataformsjs/dataformsjs/blob/master/docs/jsx-loader.md

https://github.com/dataformsjs/dataformsjs/issues/18#issuecomment-898310364

I'm the author and basically jsxLoader is tiny (6.2 kB) browser based compiler for JSX / React. I've created a separate `LazyLoad` Component that can dynamically download and compile JSX files the first time they are used.

For full details see the github issue and here is some basic code:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dataformsjs@5/js/react/jsxLoader.min.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/dataformsjs@5/js/react/es6/DataFormsJS.min.js"></script>
```

```
function CalculatorPage() {
    return (
        <LazyLoad
            scripts="calc-react.jsx"
            isLoading={<ShowLoading />}
            isLoaded="Calculator" />
    );
}
```