# Can I intercept ES6 module imports globally on my website, e.g. to do a JSX compilation?

Tags: jsx, es6-modules

When using ES6 module imports in the browser, i.e. something like

```
import test from './test.js'
```

is there a mechanism to globally intercept the loading on my website, e.g. to do a JSX compilation, before the script gets executed?
Or even any smarter ways to do it?

I am trying to [get JSX working in combination with module imports without server-side preprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68648959/how-to-make-es6-modules-and-jsx-working-without-server-side-build), so far without success...

Comment: A service worker should be able to do that. [Here](https://github.com/bahmutov/babel-service) I found an old project which seems to implement this with babel

Comment: @Bergi agree & already tried out, unfortunately also facing trouble with that approach, seems the service worker is not intercepting calls immediately after registration, but only from the second page reload onwards. Of course I could not tell the users of my page to always load it twice, cause without the service worker intercepting, things just break. Maybe I am missing something...posted this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68772017/serviceworker-not-intercepting-calls-immediately-after-installation

Comment: The Vite development server kind of does by serving as a proxy ...